# Unable to Build for IOS: Failed xcode build step

Tags: codenameone

I get this error as the last line of my build log when I send an iOS build. The android version builds without any error.

"Failed xcodebuild step"

Here is the link to the log file

https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/b970eff0-835b-4eff-bdbc-5b9076bad8ec-1529484447185-error.txt

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you just add the library? You may need to refresh libs and/or clean and build.

Comment: I didnt add anything. I've refreshed libs...sent an android build which works fine. I get the same error

https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/1d021427-7139-4bc3-b764-f42cff91f6a5-1529526729795-error.txt

Comment: You added the cn1lib for websockets and didn't fully remove it. If you add a cn1lib and don't use it then callbacks from that cn1lib can trigger compilation issues as the callback class is stripped by the JVM